# Setting signInAudience of application registration with azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I'm creating and app registration with azure cli using

```
az ad app create ...
```

function.

In the manifest of app registration there is a field:`signInAudience`
which i want to set to: `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`

Calling

```
az ad app update --id [[APP_ID]] --set signInAudience=AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount
```

returns

```
Property 'signInAudience' not found on root. Send it as an additional property .
Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version.
```

How can I change it?

Comment: It seems the `signInAudience` just only be available in the `App registrations (Preview)` currently, it is not available in `App registrations ` and azure cli.

Comment: Have you found a solution so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can update the app with `--available-to-other-tenants`

```sh
az ad app update --id xxxx --available-to-other-tenants
```

This will set `signInAudience` property in `manifest` to either `AzureADMultipleOrgs` or `AzureADMyOrg`.

Check `az ad app update -h` for more help or [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-update)

Comment: but what to do if I want to set the value to AzureADAndMicrosoftAccounts

Comment: @quadroid FYI it's now possible with the new `--sign-in-audience` parameter. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72433463/2698119).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with version 2.37.0 and above, with the new `--sign-in-audience` parameter:

```
az ad app create --display-name "My test app" --sign-in-audience AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount
```

From the [app create documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-create):

> `--sign-in-audience`
> Specifies the Microsoft accounts that are supported for the current application.
>
> accepted values: AzureADMultipleOrgs, AzureADMyOrg, AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount, PersonalMicrosoftAccount

Answer (score -1):

You can try updating it using the [App registrations (Preview) in the Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredAppsPreview). Find your app and navigate to the Manifest using the left-hand navigation. Locate the `signInAudience` property and set it to `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`. Then save your changes.

Comment: I know, I can update it in portal. But i need to be able to update it via CLI